# Widespread Bathroom Faucet Handle Seat Removal

Tags: faucet

[image]I was able to completely remove all of the handle down to the stem. I’ve spent the last 4 hours reviewing videos on what I should do next and am at a loss. None of the stems on the videos look anything like my stem.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't pry anything.  This looks like a Moen, and probably the shiny lamp-shaped part screws off, either by hand if you have a good grip or with a strap wrench.  After that,  the valve stem can be removed with a channel lock.

Search "change moen widespread washer" on youtube for lots of demos.

The bottom part, beneath the shiny lamp-shaped part, holds the valve assembly to the counter with a nut from below.  If it's tight, don't loosen it.  You don't need to remove the valve from the counter top to change the washer.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now that I know how it’s seated, I can follow your suggestions and work from there.

Comment: I was able to completely remove all of the handle down to the stem.  I’ve spent the last 4 hours reviewing videos on what I should do next and am at a loss.    None of the stems on the videos look anything like my stem.

Comment: Add a pic to the question.